# How to send email within Python program

Tags: raspbian-stretch

From within a python program, I am trying to send an email message using this command: `os.system('/home/pi/emailstart.sh')`

The `emailstart.sh` program is

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Motion Started" | mail -s "Subject" kayak@cableone.net
```

This program sends the mail when I send it from the command line but does nothing when I try to send it from within there python program.

Any observations?

Comment: It should be **#!/bin/bash**

Comment: I wonder if when running python stuff, environment variables like $PATH are set up. Can you try providing full paths to echo and mail binaries?

Comment: Ah ha, It should be os.system('./home/pi/emailstart.sh')

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to calling bash scripts from Python you can have a look at Python's [`smtplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example).

Answer (score 1):

You will need access to an SMTP server to send mail over the Internet. If your RPi doesn't have an SMTP server set up and working already, you may wish to consider using an external server. One popular choice is Google mail. If you have a Google email account, they will allow you to forward mail through their server. There is a [GitHub page](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiPyMailer) that will show you how to use Gmail as an SMTP service, and also has a small Python program that sends email messages on command; feel free to modify it for your purposes. Let us know if you have questions.